# Found non-empty schema(s) "public" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, gradle, flyway

I know this has been asked previously but I am spinning in circles here....

I have a postgres 14 database and a Springboot application running flyway-db:7.13.0 and flyway-core:8.5.10

I am using RDS. I created a new database manually using root account. When I run my springboot my flyway migration fails with the error

> Found non-empty schema(s) "public" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.

I understand the reason why this is happening but when I add the baselineVersion and baselineOnMigrate to my flyway gradle config it still doesn't work. I even added

```
flyway {
        url = dbUrl
        user = dbUser
        password = dbPassword
        schemas = ['public']
        baselineVersion = '0.0'
        baselineOnMigrate = true
        locations = ["filesystem:${dbMigrationPath}"]
       }
```

also I added

```
  spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate = true
```

to my application.properties

What confuses me the most is if I start the application pointing to the default postgres database with the root user. The migration works and it creates the flyway history table. but when I run it pointing to the newly created database it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Adding `spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true` fixed it in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turned out I needed to add the baselineOnMigration flag to my configuration

```
Flyway.configure().baselineOnMigrate(true).dataSource(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource)).load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether to automatically call baseline when migrate is executed against a non-empty schema with no schema history
table. This schema will then be initialized with the baselineVersion before executing the migrations.
Only migrations above baselineVersion will then be applied.
This is useful for initial Flyway production deployments on projects with an existing DB.
Be careful when enabling this as it removes the safety net that ensures
Flyway does not migrate the wrong database in case of a configuration mistake! (default: false)

```
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=

flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
```

I added flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true under the statement above and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).